# How to choose the best segmentation model using the area under the precision recall curve, IOU and Dice metrics?

Tags: image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am using several U-Net variants for a brain tumor segmentation task. I get the following values for the performance measures including Dice, IOU, Area under receiver-operating characteristic (AUC) curves, and Area under Precision-Recall curves (AUPRC), otherwise called the average precision (AP) computed for varying IOU thresholds in the range [0.5:0.95] in intervals of 0.05.

[image]

From the above table, I could observe that Model-2 gave better values for the IOU and Dice metrics. I could understand that Dice coefficient gives more weightage for the TPs. However, Model - 1 gives superior values for the AUC, and AP@[0.5:0.95] metrics. What parameters need to be given higher importance in model selection under these circumstances?

Comment: I'm voting to close this post because it's not related to coding issue.

Comment: @Bilal: We have such questions and appropriate answers at stackoverlfow, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268728/why-dice-coefficient-and-not-iou-for-segmentation-tasks. Where do you suggest me to put this question?

Comment: at this [network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Bilal: I do not have the required credentials to move this question to that specified link.